# How to remove connected intersecting geometry?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm using the Skin modifier to make the base mesh for a creature, to sculpt on later. But I have some self-intersections, and would like to remove all the internal geometry -- kind of like a boolean union on itself.

Here's a small example, created by using the Skin modifier on three edges of a plane:

[image: self-intersection-test]

I tried the Remesh modifier, but it just kept the internal geometry.

The *Intersect (Knife)* tool in *Self Intersect* mode easily selects the **boundaries** of the interior geometry, but I don't know how to go from there to the interior faces I want to delete.

[image: selected-intersections]

<sub>*(I'd upload the .blend file of this example, but I'm [not comfortable with blend-exchange's terms](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/narrowing-down-terms-of-blend-exchange). Yes, with this file it doesn't really matter, but it's more of a statement than anything else. I uploaded it to Github's Gist service, but I had to Base64-encode it which means Windows users are out of luck.)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could box select only the visible vertices, duplicate them, separate them (or invert the selection and delete) and then remesh it to fill the holes.

Comment: ah yes nice solution  ;)

Comment: Good idea, thanks! Unfortunately, that works for this test, but not very easily for more complicated geometry. I should probably post another picture illustrating that.